# ¿Por qué al usar dos o mas mat paginator en diferentes tablas pero en la misma pantalla ya no funciona más que el primero?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-paginator

Tengo una pantalla donde tengo tres tablas, cada una de ellas se llena con un servicio diferente, agregué el mat paginator a cada una de ellas pero el que funciona solo es el primero, de las otras dos tablas no hacen nada el paginador

html

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="scrollme">
    <form>
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="idControl">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID.</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.idControl }}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="cveEstado">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ESTADO</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="select-css" [ngClass]="{'text-red': element.cveEstado=='ERR',
        'text-green': element.cveEstado=='INP', 'text-orange': element.cveEstado=='PEN'}">
            <mat-select [(value)]="element.cveEstado" (selectionChange)="cambiarEstado($event.value, element)"
              [disabled]="!element.editar">

              <mat-option *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel" [value]="estatus.cveEstado"
                [disabled]="deshabilitarOpcion(element.cveEstado).includes(estatus.descripcion)">
                {{ estatus.descripcion }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="comentario">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>COMENTARIO</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput [value]="element.comentario" (keyup)="changeValue($event.target, element)"
                [disabled]="!element.editar" />
            </mat-form-field>
            <br>
            <span class="error" *ngIf="element.limiteExcedido">El tamaño máximo es de 15 caracteres</span>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="horaInicio">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>HORA</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput [value]="element.horaInicio" (keyup)="changeValueHora($event.target, element)"
                [disabled]="!element.editar" />
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="fechaRegistro">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>FECHAREGISTRO</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngIf="element.fechaRegistro">
              <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [value]="element.fechaRegistro"
                (dateChange)="onDateChange($event.value, element)" [disabled]="!element.editar" />
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="esValido">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ES VALIDO </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-select [(value)]="element.esValido">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let valid of esValidoArr" [value]="valid.valor">
                  {{ valid.label}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="botonSave">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>GUARDAR</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
            <button mat-button (click)="guardar(element)">Guardar</button>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
      </table>

      <mat-paginator #paginator="matPaginator" [pageIndex]="0" [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]">
      </mat-paginator>
    </form>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <form>
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource1" class="mat-elevation-z8">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="idProducto">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID PRODUCTO</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.idProducto }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="descripcionProducto">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>DESCRIPCION</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [value]="element.descripcionProducto" />
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumProd"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumProd"></tr>
    </table>

    <mat-paginator #paginator2="matPaginator" [pageIndex]="0" [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]"
      showFirstLastButtons>
    </mat-paginator>
  </form>
</div>
```

Componet.ts

```
import { Component, QueryList, ViewChild, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { Control } from './Control';
import { ControlService } from './control.service';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Estado } from './Estado.ts';
import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, UntypedFormBuilder, UntypedFormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { CatalogoProducto } from './CatalogoProducto';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'prueba-angular-material';
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'idControl',
    'cveEstado',
    'comentario',
    'horaInicio',
    'fechaRegistro',
    'esValido',
    'botonSave',
  ];
  displayedColumProd: string[] = [
    'idProducto',
    'descripcionProducto'
  ];
  estadoModel: Estado[] = [];
  control: Control[] = [];
  controlModel: Control = new Control();
  estadoSeleccionado: any;
  idSeleccionado: string = '';
  comentIngresado: string = '';
  horaIngresada: string ='';
  fechaIngresada: any;
  dataModel: any[] = [];
  horaInvalida = true;
  limiteExcedido = false;
  catProducto: CatalogoProducto[] = [];
 

  selected : any;
  
  @ViewChild('paginator') paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild('paginator2') paginator2!: MatPaginator;

  constructor(
    private controlService: ControlService,
    private dataAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>
  ) {
    this.dataAdapter.setLocale('es-MX');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    

    this.obtenerLista();
    this.obtenerListaEstados();
    this.obtenerCatalogoProducto();
    
  }

  esValidoArr = [
    { label: 'Si', valor: '1' },
    { label: 'No', valor: '0' },
  ];


  //obtiene el id y el valor del campo esValido
  select(valor:Event, row:any){
    console.log("ID   ",row.idControl);
    console.log("VALOR       ",valor);

  }

  //obtiene la lista del servicio
  dataSource: any;
  private obtenerLista() {
    this.controlService.obtenerLista().subscribe((response) => {
      this.control = response.data;
     
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.control);
     
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }

  //obtiene la lista del catalogo producto
  dataSource1: any;
  private obtenerCatalogoProducto() {
    this.controlService.obtenerCatProd().subscribe((response) => {
      this.catProducto = response.data;
      
      this.dataSource1 = new MatTableDataSource(this.catProducto);
      this.dataSource1.paginator2 = this.paginator2;
    });
  }

  //obtiene la lista de estados para el select
  private obtenerListaEstados() {
    this.controlService.obtenerEstados().subscribe((response) => {
      console.log("PRUEBA  estados" ,response.data);
      this.estadoModel = response.data;
    });
  }

  //obtiene la cve del estado que se selecciona y su id
  cambiarEstado(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.estadoSeleccionado = valor;
    this.idSeleccionado = row.idControl;

    console.log(' ID SELECC ' + this.idSeleccionado);
    console.log(' ESTADO SELECC ' + this.estadoSeleccionado);
  }

  //obtiene el valor ingresado en el input coment  y el id
  changeValue(e: any, row: any) {
    this.comentIngresado = e.value;
    console.log(' INPUT COMENT  ' + this.comentIngresado);
    if (this.comentIngresado.length > 15) {
      row.limiteExcedido = true;
      e.target.value = this.comentIngresado.slice(0, 15);
    } else {
      row.limiteExcedido = false;
    }
  }

 //obtiene el valor ingresado en el input hora, y el id
 changeValueHora(e: any, row: any) {
  this.horaIngresada = e.value;
  console.log(' INPUT HORA   ' +this.horaIngresada);
  this.validarHora();
}

validarHora() {
  console.log(' ENTRA A VALIDAR HORA');
  const regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}$");
  this.horaInvalida = !regex.test(this.horaIngresada);
  console.log('HORA '  + this.horaInvalida);
}


  //OBTIENE EL VALOR DE LA FECHA SELECCIONADA
  onDateChange(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.fechaIngresada = valor;
    console.log('FECHA SELECC  ' + this.fechaIngresada);
  }

  //funcion para darle formato a la fecha internamente
  formatDateToString(date: Date): string {
    if (date) {
      const format = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
      const locale = 'en-US';
      return formatDate(date, format, locale);
    }
    return '';
  }

  deshabilitarOpcion(cveEstado: string): string[] {
    switch (cveEstado) {
      case 'INP':
        return ['FINISHED','PENDING'];
      case 'En Proceso':
        return ['Iniciado'];
      default:
        return [];
    }
  }

  guardar(element: any) {
    if (element.editar) {
      console.log(`Desactivado para ${element.idControl}`);
      element.editar = false;

      if (this.comentIngresado == '') {
        alert('No se han modificado campos');
      } else {
        console.log(' ENTRA ELSE  ');
        this.controlModel.cveEstado = this.estadoSeleccionado;
        this.controlModel.comentario = this.comentIngresado;
        this.controlModel.idControl = this.idSeleccionado;
        this.controlModel.fechaRegistro = this.formatDateToString(
          this.fechaIngresada
        );

        console.log('prueba fecha final  ' + this.controlModel.fechaRegistro);
        this.controlService
          .updateCampo(this.controlModel)
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.controlModel = data;
            this.comentIngresado = '';
            this.estadoSeleccionado = '';
            this.fechaIngresada = '';

            alert('Agregado correctamente');
          });
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`Activado para ${element.idControl}`);
      element.editar = true;
    }
  }
}
```

No se que me esta faltando o haciendo mal que no toma el otro paginador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `#paginatorProd` le tienes que agregar `="matPaginator"`, queda así:

```
#paginatorProd=“matPaginator”
```

para hacer la referencia a cada elemento, mientras que en el componente tienes:

```
@ViewChild('paginatorProd') paginatorProd: MatPaginator;
```

Código de ejemplo:

**Componente**

```
export class TablaComponent {

  // tabla2 es duplicado de tabla.
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(tabla);
  dataSource2 = new MatTableDataSource(tabla2);

  @ViewChild('paginator') paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild('paginator2') paginator2!: MatPaginator;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource2.paginator = this.paginator2;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
    // Tabla
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">...
    </table>

    <mat-paginator
      #paginator="matPaginator"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
      showFirstLastButtons>
    </mat-paginator>

    // Tabla 2
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource2">...
    </table>

    <mat-paginator
      #paginator2="matPaginator"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
      showFirstLastButtons>
    </mat-paginator>
```

**Resultado**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo pongo asi #paginatorProd=“paginatorProd” y me manda error en la consola, que dice: No directive found with exportAs 'paginatorProd'

Comment: Es matPaginator, no paginatorProd.

Comment: Actualice la respuesta, hay varias formas de hacerlo, desde hacer una función hasta usar `QueryList` así: `@ViewChildren(MatPaginator) paginator = new QueryList<MatPaginator>();`, la forma más simple es la que puse en la respuesta.

Comment: ya probé agregando esto  #paginatorProd=“matPaginator” y poniendo en el component como pusiste y sale el mismo error No directive found with exportAs 'matPaginator'

Comment: La primer tabla está en un form, mete las otras también en un form.

Comment: ya también lo  agregue asi pero marca el mismo error

Comment: Lo estoy probando y asi funciona, pon la misma instrucción en todos los mat-paginator

Comment: De igual forma ya actualice la respuesta

Comment: actualice mi pregunta a como la modifique y ya no marca el error, pero sigue sin funcionar el segundo paginador

Comment: Checa tu código y vuelve a comparar, tienes `this.dataSource1.paginator2`

Comment: gracias, ya lo cambie y lo hace bien, pensé  que se llamaba en esta linea  this.dataSource1.paginator al mismo que defini como paginator2